# How to create a centralized syntax file that be able to recognize multiple parts with different syntaxes?

Tags: vim, windows-10, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

For i.e: I'd like to have a custom syntax file, may be called `sugar.vim` that includes multiple other syntax files(?) to have the ability to highlight, maybe a paragraph as `python.vim` and another paragraph as `javascript.vim`, may be separated by `newline` (paragraphs often distinct by `newline`)

The real case that I often catch myself writing a document (non-extension file) other than real config a specific filetype (specific extension file), but for clear readability in the document filetype (we called `sugar` above). I'm thinking about a mechanism to recognize and `highlight` different parts of **a** filetype as different syntaxes.

To narrow down this case. How would it be to have a syntax file called `sugar.vim` that would be able to recognize `python` syntax and `javascript` syntax in files that have an extension of `.sugar` then the `recognized python text` should have highlights applied as a normal python file, same for `javascript` part. All `recognized text` must be separated by newline (at least one before and one after that text)

Sample:

```
# this is a sample text for this question
# i'm writing a document that has an extension of `.sugar`

def py_func1(arg1, arg2)   # python.vim and its highlights applied here.
    print("bello world!")

square = function(x) {     # javascript.vim and its highlights applied here.
    return x * x;
};
```

System: gvim 8.1 / windows10

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1):

Vim supports that with the [`:help :syn-include`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-include) command. As it's intended for syntax script writers leveraging other syntaxes, its use is somewhat complicated, and it's not really suited for interactive, on-demand use.

My [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) provides commands and functions to set up regions in the current buffer that either use a syntax different from the buffer's 'filetype', or completely ignore the syntax. With it, it's trivial to dynamically add a particular syntax highlighting for a range of lines, and public API functions also make the programmatic definition easier.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `:help :syn-include`.

Excerpt from vim help :

> If top-level syntax items in the included syntax file are to be
>    contained within a region in the including syntax, you can use the
>    ":syntax include" command:
>
> :sy[ntax] include [@{grouplist-name}] {file-name}
>
> All syntax items declared in the included file will have the
>    "contained" flag added.  In addition, if a group list is specified,
>    all top-level syntax items in the included file will be added to
>    that list. >
>
> " In perl.vim:
>    :syntax include @Pod :p:h/pod.vim
>    :syntax region perlPOD start="^=head" end="^=cut" contains=@Pod
>
> When {file-name} is an absolute path (starts with "/", "c:", "$VAR"
>    or "") that file is sourced.  When it is a relative path
>    (e.g., "syntax/pod.vim") the file is searched for in 'runtimepath'.
>    All matching files are loaded.  Using a relative path is
>    recommended, because it allows a user to replace the included file
>    with his own version, without replacing the file that does the ":syn
>    include".

As long as you can clearly define boundaries for your embedded language regions it is fairly straight forward to achieve this.

You can also refer to https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/blob/master/syntax/markdown.vim for reference on how `tpope` embeds other syntax definitions within the markdown syntax, driven by configuration to minimise the number of language syntax's that need embedding for optimal performance.